# Filesystem corruption on seemingly healthy SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, filesystems, file-corruption

Since I replaced my HDD with an SSD (ADATA SU650) on my laptop (HP Probook 6470b) I've been getting semi-consistent filesystem corruption on two different linux installs, the first one is debian 10 and the second is arch linux.

I would sometimes get a corrupted filesystem when booting, and a prompt to fix it with fsck. Sometimes some files would get corrupted too.
This last time my system didn't want to boot and I got stuck on GRUB, booting on a live cd got me this:

> [image]

I plugged the SSD on a windows machine and used adata ssd toolbox and it seemed healthy. Here is also a smartctl test, I'm not sure how to read these results:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.7.11-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ADATA SU650
Serial Number:    2J2920009345
LU WWN Device Id: 0 000000 000000000
Firmware Version: V8X01c45
User Capacity:    120,034,123,776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Sep 28 07:26:24 2020 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    1) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x59) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  11) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0039) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       112
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       187
161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
162 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2654
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       109
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       258720
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   030    Old_age   Always       -       44
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
207 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       198
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       151
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
250 Read_Error_Retry_Rate   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       237

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               40%        90         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               10%        90         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%        90         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        60         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

The SSD was brand new when I used it the first time, could it be faulty? Or is the problem with my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

For seemingly random 'disk corruption' first suspect is the SATA cable & sockets. Your test on another machine would appear to confirm this.

Replace cable, clean all contacts, make certain there is zero pressure on any connection when the machine is re-assembled. Slight sideways pressure can wreak havoc. Standard SATA ports on mobos are a horrible under-spec imnsho.

Comment: But why would it take time (often weeks) to start corrupting the filesystem? Is there away to quickly test the sata connection is faulty?

Comment: I've never found one - things just get randomly £$%^&*!! I tried to track one down for months until I realised what it was. Over 3 or 4 months, went through 3 drives & half a dozen cables before discovering it all worked fine with the back off the machine… no pressure on the cable. I've not trusted the darn things since.

Comment: There are no sata cables on my laptop, just a large sata connection that you have to slide the hard drive case in diagonally, does the same apply?

Comment: Then I've no idea, sorry.